# Zurb Foundation navigation child menus does not stack

Tags: responsive-design, navigation, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm using Zurb Foundation responsive menu but it looks like the children navigation does not stack. I've tested it on their official [documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/responsive-navigation.html) and does not work as well. See image below, looks like the children navigation extends horizontally.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu needs to have these classes `class="vertical medium-horizontal menu"`. Only the `menu` class was used in their example. What this means is that it is displayed as `vertical` by default and changes to `horizontal` when the screen is at least medium in size; ipad, monitor, etc.